# How to prevent Unity from generating unnecessary changes after saving a scene with no actual changes

Tags: unity, scene, serialization, version-control

I was having trouble where Git shows a lot of changes (for my case, about ~3000 diff change since I have many objects in the scene) after saving a scene (.unity file) in Unity, even though there are no changes made to the scene.

[image: Diff output]
[image: More diffs]

Upon checking, I noticed Unity recompiled the scene file and some values are just in a different order.

How do we prevent this from happening?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the scene file.
2. Disable and re-enable any GameObject (just to trigger Unity to think there are changes, so you can save the scene file).
3. Save the scene file.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This bug seems to have been fixed in newer versions of Unity (e.g. 2020 LTS and 2021 LTS).**

---

As far as I know, this is caused by a bug or design flaw in the Unity Editor. When you add UI prefabs to a scene, the Editor is very aggressive about generating property overrides for most properties on your UI prefabs, even when those overrides aren't actually needed. Not only does this increase the size of the scene file, it can completely break your UI if you make changes in the prefab and those changes don't show up correctly in the scene because of undesired overrides. IIRC this problem has gotten worse in newer versions of Unity.

If you have a simple, 100% reproducible example, I'd suggest reporting this to Unity as a bug.

Comment: Can't reproduce in a new project. Occasionally I will get that when there're more changes. I'm suspecting it could be upgrading to newer unity version where it might need to upgrade the existing scene file as well

Comment: @kkl I was able to reproduce in a new project and reported it to Unity.

Comment: @kkl I think this issue has been fixed or at least partially mitigated in the last few Unity updates.